# Stripe Button not working on a custom post type template

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, posts, templates

I have a custom post type of "Properties", I am adding a stripe button on the template on this Property Post Type.

But when I click the stripe button, i get the following errors:

jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.4:2     POST webiste/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.4:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.4:2
(anonymous) @ jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=3.4.0:2
e. @ jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=3.4.0:2
S. @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.4:2
handleSubmit @ stripe-button.7c183c3003a91f048606.bundle.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ stripe-button.7c183c3003a91f048606.bundle.min.js:2
stripe-button.7c183c3003a91f048606.bundle.min.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: result is not defined
at Object. (stripe-button.7c183c3003a91f048606.bundle.min.js:2:1681)
at c (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.4:2:28447)
at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.4:2:29192)
at l (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.4:2:80201)
at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.4:2:82630)

Comment: Does anything show up in your PHP error log?